# classes with inheritance the simplified way?

Tags: class, inheritance, lua

EDIT I have found a much easier way to do this in lua but the problem is method inheritance

basically the syntax would go like this

### Object

```
object       = {}
object.base  = ?
object.value = 0

function object:create(x, y)
    local copy

    --copy table
    if type(self) == "table" then
        copy = {}  for k, v in pairs(self) do copy[k] = v:create() end
    else
        copy = self
    end

    --set base
    copy.base = self

    --set copy vars
    copy.x = x
    copy.y = y

    return copy
end

function object:update() 
    self.value = self.value + 1
end
```

### Player

```
player       = object:create()
player.value = 1

function player:create(x, y, size)
    base:create(x, y) --inherit base event
end

--automaticly inherits update event since it is not redeclared
```

I'm not sure how to go about doing this though

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance in Lua is basically implemented using [metatables](https://www.lua.org/pil/16.2.html). In code:

```
function object:new (o)
      o = o or {}
      -- Put the rest of your create function code here
      setmetatable(o, self)
      self.__index = self
      return o
    end

function object:update() 
    self.value = self.value + 1
end
```

Now create an empty Player `class` that will be a subclass of your base `Object class` and will inherit all its behavior from it.

```
Player = Object:new()
```

`Player` is now an instance of `Object`. Instantiate a new `Player` object, `p` in order to inherit the `new` method from `Object`.

```
p = Player:new{x=1, y=2, size=3}
```

This time, however, when `new` executes, the `self` parameter will refer to `player`. Therefore, the metatable of `p` will be `Player`, whose value at index `__index` is also `Player`. So, `p` inherits from `Player`, which inherits from `Object`.

Now when you'll code:

```
p:create{x=10, y=20, size=100}
```

lua won't find a `create` field in `p`, so it will look into `Player` class; it won't find a  `create` field there, too, so it will look into `Object` and there it will finds the original implementation of `create`. The same thing will happen with the `update` function.

Of course `Player` class can redefine any method inherited from its superclass, `Object`. So for example you can redefine -if you want- the `create` function:

```
function Player:create()
   --New create code for Player
end
```

Now when you'll call `p:create{x=10, y=20, size=190}`, Lua will not access the `Object` class, because it finds the new `create` function in `Player` first.

Comment: thankyou but I need to be able to call base:<method>() to inherit the method so I reduce the amount of repeating code.

Comment: You want to inherit  your `create` method in your `Player` class, no? This is automatically done when you call `p:create{x=10, y=20, size=100}`

Comment: oh so I don't need to call base:update() in my player:update to inherit obj:update()?

Comment: so I have a another question is this how its set up? https://pastebin.com/yunYqfxf? I return self in the create function?

Answer (score 0):

You are making a reference to `base` directly, whereas, it is actually an attribute of your player object:

```
function player:create(x, y, size)
    self.base:create(x, y)
end
```

Comment: sorry it was just pusado code I wrote up since I am using pico 8.
but I still would like to know the best way to do this without too many charaters since pico 8 has a 65535 charater limit